# text on anchor changes when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change the content of an anchor when hovered? i have this sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6ao29eg/)
i want to change the about anchor to some like My bio when hovered. and something else also for the home. the content attribute doesn't seem to work well with this.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li a:hover { color: red; content: 'Content'; }
```

Comment: "content property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content." not with normal elements. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Re your comment below. You do not need to duplicate the code with the `hover`/`data` solutions provided. They work for any number of links.

Comment: Based on a comment you made below, you need to be careful with transitions in a non-CSS solution as you may get stuck on the wrong state.

Comment: your code works well but it doesn't look good for the UI without the transition. if i can't put a transition on the js might as well not to integrate it.

Comment: What sort of transition do you want on these? Example with fade added to answer: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/10/

Comment: That works perfectly but i can't add a data content on my menu. im using a dynamic menu on wordpress so i cant add any attribute on the menu

Comment: Always best to mention important restrictions up front :) @MariaMadalina uses an array and indexing below. You could combine the solutions.

Comment: e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/11/ Updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "content property is used with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, to insert generated content." not with normal elements.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

You can change it using jQuery:

```
$('li a').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('text', $(this).text());
    $(this).text('Content');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/2/

This version simply saves the text to data on the element on `mouseenter`, and restores it on `mouseleave`. You can also use `hover` passing the same two functions.

e.g.

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).data('text', $(this).text()).text('Content');
}, function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/5/

*I notice several other clever CSS-only solutions have been provided, so the choice depends on how much you can change your content, vs adding code.*

If you want different text, use a data attribute:

```
<li><a href="#" data-content="About me!">About</a></li>
```

e.g.

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).data('text', $(this).text()).text($(this).data('content'));
}, function(){
    $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/8/

### Update to use a transition (fade) as requested:

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(function(){
       $(this).data('text', $(this).text()).text($(this).data('content')).fadeIn();
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).data('text')).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/10/

### Further update now the rules have changed :)

As the HTML content apparently *cannot* be modified, use the index position of the `LI` combined with an array of text items:

```
var content = ["About me!", "My home!"];
$('li').hover(function(){
    var $a = $('a', this);
    $a.stop(true,true).fadeOut(function(){
       $a.data('text', $a.text()).text(content[$(this).index()]).fadeIn();
    });
}, function(){
    var $a = $('a', this);
    $a.stop(true,true).fadeOut(function(){
        $a.text($a.data('text')).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/s6ao29eg/11/

*Credit to `@MariaMadalina` who used an array before even knowing the HTML could not be modified :)*

Comment: this is nice. but i want all my li a content to be different. e.g. About  change to my bio then home change to go back or something else maybe...

Comment: One option is to stick the "new" values on a `data-` attribute. I will add an example.

Answer (score 3):

Really sounds like a job for JS. CSS only solution via pseudo elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpdoby91/

```
.about:before { content: 'About'; }
.home:before { content: 'Home'; }

ul li a:hover:before { content: 'Content'; }
```

JavaScript Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bctaxauo/1/

```
$('ul li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).data('prevText', $(this).text()).text('New Content!');
}, function() {
    $(this).text($(this).data('prevText');
});
```

Comment: do you have any reference for the JS? this works really well but I might have problem with the structuring of my menu with this.

Comment: Indeed a job for JS as there's a big chance the content here is meaningfull and not only for UI purpose. Moving this content to CSS has an impact on accessibility (I'm quite sure screen readers can't handle pseudo-content but I might be wrong) and is contrary to the content/presentation separation principle. This becomes really clear when you've got a multilingual site and you need to add extra rules in your CSS to support various languages... when translations ends up in CSS, that's a good indicator you're going the wrong direction. But +1 for showing the OP exactly what he asked for.

Comment: I added a JS/jQuery based solution, which stores the prev text as well. Should work about like this.

Comment: can you help me with this? http://jsfiddle.net/bctaxauo/2/ i manage to make a different function for each anchor but the 2nd anchor doesnt change back to the default content

Comment: Your selectors are wrong. You meant to do "ul li:first-child a", using your way it always selects the first <a> in a <li>. I would suggest you assign classes to each invidivual a tag, that would simplify things a lot. (and yes, I had to update the fiddle to correct syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Just hide "hover text" when in normal state and switch display when on hover:

```css
.menu li:hover .unhover {
  display: none;
}
.menu li:hover .hover {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li .unhover {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li .hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="unhover">Home</span>
      <span class="hover">Visit home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a jquery snippet

```
   $('li#about').hover(function() {
    $("a", this ).text( "something" );
  }, function() {
    $("a", this ).text( "About" );
  });
```

Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/s6ao29eg/3/

**EDIT**:
I made some modifications towards a more scalable solution.

```
var replacementText=["Something 1","Something 2"];

$('li').hover(function() {
    var myindex =  $(this).index();
    var myText=replacementText[myindex];
     $("a", this).data('original', $("a",this).text()).text(myText);

  }, function() {
      var myindex =  $(this).index();

    $("a",this).text($("a",this).data('original'));

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6ao29eg/9/

Comment: This solution does not scale well (imagine the code required for 20 links).

Comment: Yes you are right, but neither hard coding the replacement text does not scale well. Anyways it solves the problem at hand. It's true there's place for more improvements.

Comment: Like `sonam gupta`'s answer, this does not even cover the two links in the original question. If you add the second one you will see this is not a good approach to the problem as the code keeps expanding for each link added.

Comment: That edit *is* an improvement. I would suggest however adding `data-` attributes, rather than an array in the code, as you are separating parallel sets of information (which makes maintenance harder). It also simplifies the code as you won't care about indexes. :)

Comment: The rules have now changed (they cannot modify the HTML) and your answer provides a useful alternative :) I have given credit in my latest update for your use of an array. The only thing you are lacking now is the transitions they requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using jQuery.

Add an id to your li as:

```
 <li><a href="#" id="about">About</a>
```

and add this jQuery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#about').hover(function(){
    $(this).text('');
        $(this).text('My Bio');

    });
     $('#about').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).text('');
        $(this).text('about');

    });
});
```

Fiddle link is:http://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/w5fh140q/

or also do like this if you have multiple li's

http://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/gayph16x/

Comment: This solution does not scale well (imagine the code required for 20 links).

Comment: so u can assign a common class to all and then use .each function of jquey

Comment: But you have hard-wired the text e.g. "About", so that will not work. You need to change your approach :)

Comment: we can also pass dynamic values for each new li.At that time i have given answer as per his requirement and as a sample that this is also the way of doing this

Comment: Best you expand your example and see what happens. The question shows two links so far. You have hard-wired the simplest case of one link. You have also used `mouseout` with `hover`, when `hover` can do both by itself. *Do you really wish to insist this is a good solution?* :)

Comment: Everyone have there suggestions and can give. The thing is the person who is in need will decide which one is the best.I know how to do it in common if it has more than 20 values.But at that time i have to provide answer as per his requirement and he only asked to change the about text.

Comment: i find this more convenient for me though is it possible to have this on a smooth transition? http://jsfiddle.net/w5fh140q/1/

Comment: For using with multiple values u can also try this:http://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/gayph16x/

Comment: @Michael Pon: Duplicating code *per element* is always a poor choice for code maintenance. Either *data-drive* it (several solution provided) or content drive it (several of the CSS-only solutions do this). Also `mouseout` is redundant with `hover` as `hover` supports a 2-function version.

Comment: @sonam gupta: A few points re your updated version. An `each` is seldom required to operate on multiple elements in jQuery (and not required there). You are setting text to `''` for no reason. `data` is not a valid HTML attribute. You wanted to use a `data-` *prefixed* attribute and `data()`, not `attr()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, and a little color trick to hide the original text.

```
ul li a:hover {
    color: transparent;
}
ul li a:hover:before {
    content: "Content";
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
}
```

Just by the way, why would you want to use a `<ul>` to nest your `<a>` elements? You are removing all styles from the list anyway. Most of the time, what you need is just well-styled `<a>` tags; only nest them in a list if you're structuring the data as a list, which means you likely want to have something like bullet points preceding each `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Css only solution

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"> <span class="visible">About</span> <span class="hover"> My Bio</span> </a></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li a span.hover{
    display:none;}
ul li a:hover span.hover{
    display:block;
}
ul li a:hover span.visible{
    display:none;
}
```